# Adding HTML tags using th:text in thymeleaf

Tags: html, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

How can I add HTML tags into a th:text so the tags become visual?

An example of this would be the following:

A view variable called htmlcode gets injected with the value

```
<b>bla</b>
```

The view itself looks like

```
<div th:text="*{htmlcode}"><p>defaultcode</p></div>
```

Now I want the result to be something like

```
<div><b>bla</b></div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by using th:utext instead of th:text. This way, the HTML tags are added unescaped. Obviously, this has to be used with caution, to prevent XSS attacks.